# How should i compile bibliography using MDPI template?

Tags: bibliographies, templates

I got this warning trying to compile bibliography using MDPI template in LaTeX:

```
There were undefined citations.
```

This is my code:

```
 %=================================================================
    \documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi} 
    \graphicspath{ {Figures/} }
    \usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn,longtable}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{adjustbox,tabularx,ragged2e}
    \usepackage{xurl}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Pa}{Pa}
    \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
    %=================================================================
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

    \begin{document}

    some text

    \cite{Aoki2007} 

    \reftitle{References}

    % Please provide either the correct journal abbreviation (e.g. according to the “List of Title Word Abbreviations” http://www.issn.org/services/online-services/access-to-the-ltwa/) or the full name of the journal.
    % Citations and References in Supplementary files are permitted provided that they also appear in the reference list here. 

    %=====================================
    % References, variant A: external bibliography
    %=====================================
    \externalbibliography{yes}
    \bibliography{biblio.bib}

    \end{document}
```

this is an example of my .bib file:

```
@article{Aoki2007,
    author = {Aoki, Hisashi and Matsukura, Yukinori},
    doi = {10.1002/esp},
    file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Elisa/Dropbox (Geomatica{\_}DSFTA)/dottorato Eli/Letteratura/letteratura{\_}strumenti/Equot/Aoki{\_}et{\_}al-2007-A new technique for non-destructive field.pdf:pdf},
    pages = {1759--1769},
    title = {{A new technique for non-destructive field measurement of rock-surface strength : an application of the Equotip hardness tester to}},
    volume = {1769},
    year = {2007}
}
@article{Aoki2008,
abstract = {In order to utilize the Equotip hardness tester, originally developed in the field of metallic engineering, as an indirect method to predict the unconfined compressive strength (UCS) of rock, laboratory tests were undertaken to establish the UCS, Equotip hardness (L-value) and porosity of nine rock types. Using existing data from Verwaal and Mulder (Int J Rock Mech Min Sci Geomech Abstr 30:659 662, 1993) and the results of laboratory tests, an equation relating UCS (MPa) and L-value obtained from single impacts (Ls) and porosity (n {\%})was derived, which provides a close approximation of the UCS value. An equation to relate UCS and Equotip hardness is also presented, although this is less accurate. It is considered Equotip testing has advantages over the commonly used Schmidt hammer test.},
author = {Aoki, Hisashi and Matsukura, Yukinori},
doi = {10.1007/s10064-007-0116-z},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Elisa/Dropbox (Geomatica{\_}DSFTA)/dottorato Eli/Letteratura/letteratura{\_}strumenti/Equot/AOKI{\_}2008{\_}Equotip hardness.pdf:pdf},
issn = {14359529},
journal = {Bulletin of Engineering Geology and the Environment},
keywords = {Equotip hardness tester,Intact rocks,Rock hardness,Unconfined compressive strength},
number = {1},
pages = {23--29},
title = {{Estimating the unconfined compressive strength of intact rocks from Equotip hardness}},
volume = {67},
year = {2008}
}
@article{bortolotti2001geology,
    title={Geology of central and eastern Elba Island, Italy},
    author={Bortolotti, Valerio and Fazzuoli, Milvio and Pandeli, Enrico and Principi, Gianfranco and Babbini, Amedeo and Corti, Simone},
    journal={Ofioliti},
    volume={26},
    number={2a},
    pages={97--150},
    year={2001}
}
@incollection{carmignani2001inner,
    title={Inner Northern Apennines},
    author={Carmignani, Luigi and Decandia, Francesco Antonio and Disperati, Leonardo and Fantozzi, Pier Lorenzo and Kligfield, Roy and Lazzarotto, Antonio and Liotta, Domenico and Meccheri, Marco},
    booktitle={Anatomy of an Orogen: the Apennines and adjacent Mediterranean Basins},
    pages={197--213},
    year={2001},
    publisher={Springer}
}
@incollection{castellarin2001alps,
    title={Alps-Apennines and Po Plain-frontal Apennines relations},
    author={Castellarin, Alberto},
    booktitle={Anatomy of an Orogen: the Apennines and adjacent Mediterranean Basins},
    pages={177--195},
    year={2001},
    publisher={Springer}
}
@article{day1977field,
    title={Field assessment of rock hardness using the Schmidt test hammer},
    author={Day, MJ},
    journal={British Geomorphology Research Group Technical Bulletin},
    volume={18},
    pages={19--29},
    year={1977}
}
```

I already tried using Biblatex but they seem incompatible

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You should not add the file extension in the bibliography. Try to replace `\bibliography{biblio.bib}` with `\bibliography{biblio}`. Before compiling delete all the unnecessary files from your working directory (*.aux, *.bbl, *.blg, *.log, *.out, *.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

In the following, I am providing step by step how to use Bibtex in the MDPI latex template. It took my almost three hours to figure it out.

Steps:

1. Bring the bib file into the directory that you desire. For me, I will put it in the folder containing `.tex` file.
2. Either remove completely the `Mdpi.bst` or change the name for a moment. You will find the file inside the folder named "definitions" downloaded from the Mdpi website
3. Uncomment the following `\externalbibliography{yes}` `\bibliography{your reference file}` in the tex file
4. Run the tex file once
5. Now, go and bring back the `mdpi.bst` again by rewriting the name again if you change it or a copy found from the folder downloaded from mdpi
6. It will work. You asked how. I would say that I do not know.
7. By the way, make sure to cite any paper after step 5. Otherwise, the error will show up again and you will have to do the steps again, unfortunately!!
   8-Update: I have noticed that after doing the previous steps there will be a new file that will be used for the references. For any reason that you want to update any reference or to add a new reference, update the following file, not the bib one (xxxxxx.bib.bak)